# Cannot open TCP channel on 127.0.0.1 port 555 (SocketException: No Such Host Is Known)

Tags: c#, tcp, windows-services, socketexception, quartz.net-2.0

I have been running a Quartz scheduler Windows service for about 2 years on `127.0.0.1` port `555`. Starting a couple of days ago, I can no longer start my service. When I look in the code, I see that I cannot start a `TcpChannel` object.

```
IChannel chan;
chan = new TcpChannel(props, null, formatprovider);
```

When I do a `netstat` on my cmd, I do not find the address in either *Listening* or *Established*. I also cannot find any new rules on my Firewall that concerns this port.

The service is based on Quartz.net scheduler.

**Service log:**

```
2016-02-25 10:19:58,847 [9] INFO  Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory [(null)] - Quartz.NET properties loaded from configuration file 'C:\Users\pedram.mobedi\Documents\GitHub\Postbag\build\Debug\quartz.config'
2016-02-25 10:19:58,958 [9] INFO  Quartz.Util.DBConnectionManager [(null)] - Registering datasource 'default' with db provider: 'Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.Common.DbProvider'
2016-02-25 10:19:58,965 [9] INFO  Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory [(null)] - Using default implementation for object serializer
2016-02-25 10:19:58,996 [9] INFO  Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory [(null)] - Using custom data access locking (synchronization): Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore
2016-02-25 10:19:59,002 [9] INFO  Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory [(null)] - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
2016-02-25 10:19:59,099 [9] INFO  Quartz.Core.SchedulerSignalerImpl [(null)] - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: Quartz.Core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2016-02-25 10:19:59,107 [9] INFO  Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler [(null)] - Quartz Scheduler v.2.2.4.400 created.
2016-02-25 10:19:59,128 [9] INFO  Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX [(null)] - JobStoreTX initialized.
2016-02-25 10:19:59,263 [9] INFO  Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler [(null)] - Scheduler QuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
2016-02-25 10:19:59,270 [9] INFO  Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler [(null)] - Scheduler QuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
2016-02-25 10:19:59,287 [9] INFO  Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler [(null)] - Scheduler QuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED Shutdown complete.
2016-02-25 10:19:59,321 [9] ERROR Quartz.Server.QuartzServer [(null)] - Server initialization failed:Unable to bind scheduler to remoting.
Quartz.SchedulerException: Unable to bind scheduler to remoting. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.GetMachineIp()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel.SetupMachineName()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IServerChannelSinkProvider sinkProvider, IAuthorizeRemotingConnection authorizeCallback)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IServerChannelSinkProvider sinkProvider)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IClientChannelSinkProvider clientSinkProvider, IServerChannelSinkProvider serverSinkProvider)
   at Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter.RegisterRemotingChannelIfNeeded() in c:\Users\pedram.mobedi\Documents\GitHub\Postbag\Quartz.NET-2.2.4\src\Quartz\Simpl\RemotingSchedulerExporter.cs:line 120
   at Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter.Bind(IRemotableQuartzScheduler scheduler) in c:\Users\pedram.mobedi\Documents\GitHub\Postbag\Quartz.NET-2.2.4\src\Quartz\Simpl\RemotingSchedulerExporter.cs:line 71
   at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.Bind() in c:\Users\pedram.mobedi\Documents\GitHub\Postbag\Quartz.NET-2.2.4\src\Quartz\Core\QuartzScheduler.cs:line 375
   at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.Initialize() in c:\Users\pedram.mobedi\Documents\GitHub\Postbag\Quartz.NET-2.2.4\src\Quartz\Core\QuartzScheduler.cs:line 352
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.Initialize() in c:\Users\pedram.mobedi\Documents\GitHub\Postbag\Quartz.NET-2.2.4\src\Quartz\Core\QuartzScheduler.cs:line 366
   at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.Instantiate() in c:\Users\pedram.mobedi\Documents\GitHub\Postbag\Quartz.NET-2.2.4\src\Quartz\Impl\StdSchedulerFactory.cs:line 1046
   at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.GetScheduler() in c:\Users\pedram.mobedi\Documents\GitHub\Postbag\Quartz.NET-2.2.4\src\Quartz\Impl\StdSchedulerFactory.cs:line 1120
   at Quartz.Server.QuartzServer.GetScheduler() in c:\Users\pedram.mobedi\Documents\GitHub\Postbag\Quartz.NET-2.2.4\server\Quartz.Server\QuartzServer.cs:line 62
   at Quartz.Server.QuartzServer.Initialize() in c:\Users\pedram.mobedi\Documents\GitHub\Postbag\Quartz.NET-2.2.4\server\Quartz.Server\QuartzServer.cs:line 47 [See nested exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is known
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.GetMachineIp()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel.SetupMachineName()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IServerChannelSinkProvider sinkProvider, IAuthorizeRemotingConnection authorizeCallback)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IServerChannelSinkProvider sinkProvider)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IClientChannelSinkProvider clientSinkProvider, IServerChannelSinkProvider serverSinkProvider)
   at Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter.RegisterRemotingChannelIfNeeded() in c:\Users\pedram.mobedi\Documents\GitHub\Postbag\Quartz.NET-2.2.4\src\Quartz\Simpl\RemotingSchedulerExporter.cs:line 120
   at Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter.Bind(IRemotableQuartzScheduler scheduler) in c:\Users\pedram.mobedi\Documents\GitHub\Postbag\Quartz.NET-2.2.4\src\Quartz\Simpl\RemotingSchedulerExporter.cs:line 71
   at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.Bind() in c:\Users\pedram.mobedi\Documents\GitHub\Postbag\Quartz.NET-2.2.4\src\Quartz\Core\QuartzScheduler.cs:line 375
   at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.Initialize() in c:\Users\pedram.mobedi\Documents\GitHub\Postbag\Quartz.NET-2.2.4\src\Quartz\Core\QuartzScheduler.cs:line 352]
```

**Update:** Hosts file

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost
```

**Update 2**: quartz.config

```
# Quartz Config

quartz.threadPool.type = Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz
quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
#quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = Normal

# Settings for using Quartz as a windows service
quartz.scheduler.exporter.type = Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter, Quartz
quartz.scheduler.exporter.port = 555
quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName = Postbag
quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType = tcp
quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelName = httpQuartz

# SQLite settings
quartz.jobStore.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz
quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz
quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
quartz.jobStore.dataSource = default
quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = qrtz_
quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SQLiteDelegate, Quartz
quartz.dataSource.default.provider = SQLite-10
quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString = Data Source=.\jobs.db;Version=3
```

Comment: Have you had a look at your hosts file?

Comment: @Pikoh what do you mean by "hosts file"?

Comment: [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/972034)

Comment: It seems ok..it was just a suggestion

Comment: There is no IP address shown in your code. Perhaps someone altered the configuration to not use `127.0.0.1`, but another unknown hostname.

Comment: @CodeCaster is right,check your quartz.config

Comment: @Pikoh Added quartz.config to the question.

Comment: The problem is in the `props` dictionary you pass to `TcpChannel`, which contains an invalid hostname. Debug your code and inspect that variable. I guess it's `exporter.bindName = Postbag`.

Comment: @CodeCaster props contains the two values: `port:555` and `name:httpQuartz`.

Comment: Try adding to your hosts file this line `127.0.0.1       httpQuartz`

Comment: @Pikoh I tried to no avail.

Comment: @Pikoh I also uninstalled all my Windows updates for the last two months but I still don't see any changes. This is really annoying.

Comment: @Pikoh knowing me and my colleague who are working under the same network are running through this problem (we have tried the older version of the program as well) and then another colleague of mine who's working under another network with the same program does not face this issue raises suspicion on new changes in the network. But I am running this on local host. That is why I am confused.

Comment: Is it a corporate network? Try also in a cmd window to ping 127.0.0.1 and httpQuartz to see if you got a response

Comment: @Pikoh yes it's a corporate network and yes I can ping `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Well, being a corporate network maybe admin has changed something in your machine or in the network (maybe something is blocking the connections to localhost or another program using it). What i would try is to change the Quartz config to use your local ip instead the localhost and see if that way works. Sorry i can't help you more :)

Comment: @Pikoh But there is no mentioning of IP in my `quartz.config`. Only the port which is 555.

Comment: @Pikoh I have disabled my entire firewall and still no luck. i seriously have no clue anymore but thanks for you help.

Comment: @Pikoh I am not sure if I should post this as answer but our network administrator responded after four days of with "We made some certificate changes to the NLS component in DirectAccess." All is back to normal and there was nothing wrong with the program.

Answer (score 0):

That mean you have bind a host name that does not exists. Maybe you have point it to another location.

1, Have you edited the firewall rule? May be you have block your program or you have blocked all the access to 127.0.0.1

2, Is your host name a domain name? If it is, that means the domain is no longer points to this machine. You should re-point it in HOST file:

Press Win+R, enter following command:

```
notepad.exe %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Then you can check if the domain is already in that file. If it is and with a beginning of "#", remove the "#". If not, enter the following:

```
127.0.0.1 [your domain name]
```

for example:

```
127.0.0.1 test.cn
```

3, if the host name is "127.0.0.1", it shouldn't happen. That may be the fault with your operation system

Comment: Answers are not the place for guesses, and the hosts file is already posted in the question.